# Doesn't exist request ConvertEmailToCase?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

I make automatic test for CRM in C# and i need create test for converting email to case, but i didn't find request, which is doing this. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, a "ConvertEmailToCaseRequest" does not exist.

You'll have to define a creation logic manually.

Create step of an e-mail plugin, or a workflow that's triggered on the creation of an e-mail might be proper places to implement your logic.